# Sencha touch and Cordova detect locale

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I've been trying to implement integration for my sencha touch 2.2.x app. 
My problem is not exactly the creation of js or json file that contains all the key/value pairs. My problem is the actual detection of the locale and acting accordingly.

I am using `navigator.globalization.getLocaleName()` provided by Cordova, and I have a global variable 'appLocale' initialized in the launch function of app.js. However, when defining a class like the my Main.js below, the value {title: ' '} is set way before I can get the locale from the Cordova API.

Is there another way for me to get the locale or possibly another place to put the `getLocaleName()` method?

Here is my Main.js file

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',

    config: {
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            items: {
                title: 'Get Started',
                iconCls: 'action',

                items: [
                    {
                        docked: 'top',
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        title: 'i18n.getTranslation('hello', appLocale)'
                    }]
            }
     }
});
```

This is my app.js file:

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.util.i18n'
    ],

    views: [
        'Main'
    ],

    launch: function() {

        navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
             function (locale) {appLocale = locale.value},
             function () {alert('Error getting locale\n');}
        );            

        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main'));    
    }
});
```

P.S. `window.navigator.language` always returns 'en' in the Android emulator even when I change the locale. I assume this is just for a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the initComponent() method - where you can use something like:

```
//...

initComponent : function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        title: 'i18n.getTranslation('hello', appLocale)'
    });

    this.callParent();
},
//...
```

This way, any localized text is set during object *initialization*, not class *definition*.

Comment: are you saying that i cannot have the locale on class definition?

Comment: If the locale were loaded before you *defined* the class, you could. It's safer to do it at initialization time.

Comment: And for what it's worth, why not put the Ext.Viewport.add() line inside the callback of your getLocaleName() method... that way nothing happens until the locale is loaded.

Comment: is there any way for me to define the sencha touch classes in the callback method of getLocaleName()? This would be ideal.